# How many Channel Points would I need to complete the game just by skipping?

Tags: oldtv

I've been attempting to complete the game [OLDTV](http://store.steampowered.com/app/643270/) just by using the in-game skip mechanic, though I have not been able to reach the end by doing so. The cost to skip constantly increases every few channels and every time I have attempted to do so I've always been left with too little CP to reach past Africa.

Is there an exact number of CP I'd need to complete the whole game just by skipping?

Comment: Huh. I didn't think Stack Exchange allowed single-character tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to farm around **3000CP** in order to skip from the beginning all the way to the end. The exact number, in fact, has been found to be **2912**.

Source: [This](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1079095778) Steam guide.